# Configuring Coffeescript SBT in Build.scala not build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

Often I come across some instructions which tell me how to add a SBT tool to `build.sbt`, but actually I have a `Build.scala`, not a `build.sbt`. So I want to know how to do the same in my `Build.scala`?

The particular case that is causing me trouble is [Coffeescript SBT](http://github.com/softprops/coffeescripted-sbt) which has instructions for how to add it to a `build.sbt`. However I don't have a `built.sbt`, I have a `Build.scala`, so I don't know what to do.

---

The code [referenced here](https://github.com/softprops/coffeescripted-sbt/issues/9) also helps to solve this problem.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without more information about your `Build.scala`. Please provide it if possible.

Comment: Also, you can use `build.sbt` and `Build.scala` at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options:

1. Go ahead and create build.sbt with the line given in the CoffeeScript instructions.  It can coexist with Build.scala.
2. In Build.scala, find the "settings" line within the project and add `++ coffeeSettings` to it.  You may also need `import coffeescript.Plugin.coffeeSettings` at the top.

Comment: This worked for me. Where I have the `... = Project( ... settings = ` I added the coffeeSettings joined with other ones by the ++. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally I still use plugins.sbt in projects that use Build.scala for their main configuration.

Just add project/plugins.sbt with the resolver and addSbtPlugin lines.you need.